# How to load current month records from SQL loader?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I think what it is possible with WHEN section but can t found documentation about it. Control file:

```
load data INFILE 'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\oracle-18\info.txt'
 REPLACE INTO TABLE lab18 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
( 
  integervalue "round(:integervalue, 2)",
  charvalue "upper(:charvalue)", 
  datevalue date "YYYY-MM-DD" /////need to load data with current month
)
```

Comment: I dont think that you can filter records based on sql function on date. You must go with the external table. Load all data and filter it with where clause on external table

Answer (score 0):

`WHEN` clause is what you're looking for, but - you can't use any functions in it so you'll have to switch to something else. As @Tejash commented, an **external table** is one - a good, actually - choice.

Here's a walkthrough, see if it helps.

To set default data format for this session:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL>
```

Input data, stored in `lab18.txt` (the first two rows belong to current month, which is December 2019 and only those two should be loaded into the `lab18` table):

```
100.556;Little;2019-12-23
20.976;Foot;2019-12-20
76.23;Michael;2019-11-25
20.2;Scott;2019-07-13
```

Target table:

```
SQL> desc lab18
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 INTEGERVALUE                                       NUMBER
 CHARVALUE                                          VARCHAR2(10)
 DATEVALUE                                          DATE

SQL>
```

SQL*Loader control file:

```
LOAD DATA
infile lab18.txt
replace
INTO TABLE lab18
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
  integervalue  "round(replace(:integervalue, '.', ','), 2)",
  charvalue     "upper(:charvalue)",
  datevalue     "to_date(:datevalue, 'yyyy-mm-dd')"
)
```

Why do I need it, if we won't use SQL*Loader? Because we put some effort in creating it, and SQL*Loader is capable of converting it into a useful `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` script. Here's how: pay attention to `external_table=generate_only`, as it will put those *useful statements* into the log file.

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test14.ctl external_table=generate_only

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Pro 23 11:17:00 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.


SQL>
```

Now, edit the log file and extract commands we're interested in. As I already have a *directory* (named `EXT_DIR`), I'll slightly modify the `CREATE TABLE` command:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE EXT_LAB18
  2  (
  3    "INTEGERVALUE" VARCHAR(4000),
  4    "CHARVALUE" VARCHAR(4000),
  5    "DATEVALUE" VARCHAR(4000)
  6  )
  7  ORGANIZATION external
  8  (
  9    TYPE oracle_loader
 10    DEFAULT DIRECTORY EXT_DIR
 11    ACCESS PARAMETERS
 12    (
 13      RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE CHARACTERSET EE8MSWIN1250
 14      BADFILE 'EXT_DIR':'lab18.bad'
 15      LOGFILE 'test14.log_xt'
 16      READSIZE 1048576
 17      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";" LDRTRIM
 18      MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
 19      REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
 20      (
 21        "INTEGERVALUE" CHAR(255)
 22          TERMINATED BY ";",
 23        "CHARVALUE" CHAR(255)
 24          TERMINATED BY ";",
 25        "DATEVALUE" CHAR(255)
 26          TERMINATED BY ";"
 27      )
 28    )
 29    location
 30    (
 31      'lab18.txt'
 32    )
 33  )REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

Table created.

SQL>
```

I modified lines:

- 1 - renamed the table
- 10 and 14 - renamed directory

Below it (in the log file), you'll see the `INSERT INTO` statement:

```
SQL> INSERT /*+ append */ INTO LAB18
  2  (
  3    INTEGERVALUE,
  4    CHARVALUE,
  5    DATEVALUE
  6  )
  7  SELECT
  8    round(replace("INTEGERVALUE", '.', ','), 2),
  9    upper("CHARVALUE"),
 10    to_date("DATEVALUE", 'yyyy-mm-dd')
 11  FROM EXT_LAB18
 12  WHERE to_char(to_date(datevalue, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'mm.yyyy') = to_char(sysdate, 'mm.yyyy');

2 rows created.

SQL>
```

I modified lines:

- 11 - fixed external table name
- 12 - I wrote the `WHERE` clause myself

The result:

```
SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * From lab18;

INTEGERVALUE CHARVALUE  DATEVALUE
------------ ---------- ----------
      100,56 LITTLE     23.12.2019
       20,98 FOOT       20.12.2019

SQL>
```

Basically, quite a simple task, after all.